# Sign in with Apple - Manual Form

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

App submissions to the app store which contain social logins are required to have a manual log in form along side the other logins (I am assuming this incase the 3rd party SDKs break then the user still has a method to log in).

Since apple have released their native 'Sign in with apple' capability (WWDC 2019) does this mean we can submit apps without a manual form? or will this still be a requirement?

I cannot find anything in the documentation to suggest either way.

Comment: I think the requirement to have a non-social login is a) in case people don't have a social network account and/or b) in case they don't want to share their social network details with you (You might have noticed Apple is pretty big on privacy :) ). Apple haven't yet updated the App Store guidelines, so we will have to wait and see what they say.

Comment: Scroll down to the end of the page: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=06032019j

Comment: Hi, But can we implement the 'sign in with apple' without any other login method?

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is only if your app have social network login (Facebook, Google).
If your app uses a build in login (user/password), you don't need to implement.

Comment: Hi, But can we implement the 'sign in with apple' without any other login method?

Comment: Of course! You can use to receive user information. See this article to implement https://link.medium.com/Tf12k8TOFX

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, if your app is...

- **NOT USING THIRD PARTY LOGIN**

  If your app is not using any Third party login services then you **do not need to implement login with Apple** feature in your app.
- **USING NATIVE SIGN-IN/SIGNUP**

  If your app is using native sign-in/sign-up for user(user fill registration form and then login), then also you **do not need to implement login with Apple** in your app
- **USING THIRD PARTY LOGIN**

  If your app is using third party login Services like Facebook login, google login, Twitter login, etc. then You **have to implement Sign in With Apple** in your app.
- **USING THIRTY PARTY LOGIN + NATIVE SIGN-IN/SIGNUP(MIXED APPROACH)**

  If your app allows user to sign up via email by filling a registration form and also offers third party login then your app **must implement Sign in with Apple**.

Comment: If I were to submit an app for review with only the Apple sign in as the only login option, will it be accepted?

Comment: I think app won't reject as they won't discourage usage of Apple ID alone. They enforcing sign in with Apple if third party login is used but they did not say that sign in with Apple can't be used alone.